# Why is Android resource naming so specific?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've developed some basic Android apps for quite some time, but never bothered looking this up... but why does Android have specific naming requirements for resources? As mentioned in this book: [Android Apps for Absolute Beginners By Wallace Jackson](https://books.google.com/books?id=IUZ3J64ypdMC&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=what%20does%20android%20apps%20only%20take%20underscores%20for%20file%20names&source=bl&ots=CSIopdnxKC&sig=ACfU3U1zGhoLh97B6oxQQpwDDggGOj0DoQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwje78SK85_pAhXSvp4KHTg2DLcQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=what%20does%20android%20apps%20only%20take%20underscores%20for%20file%20names&f=false), there is certain criteria such as:

- Only underscore characters
- Only lowercase letters

In this book, they also mention "this is one of the many anomalies of Android programming".

I'm just simply wondering why? Is it that difficult to accept dashes and/or uppercase characters for referencing UI resources for Android app development?

Comment: Questions of the form "why did Developer X make Decision Y?" are rarely good for Stack Overflow. Often, the only party who can make a definitive answer is Developer X, who is unlikely to see and respond to the question. Part of the limitation is that resources become Java symbols (`R.drawable.foo`), so the name has to be a valid Java symbol. Part of the limitation IIRC was to avoid concerns about case sensitivity of developer filesystems (thinking back to old Windows versions).

Comment: Gotcha, and totally agree. This seemed like an interesting question to me just because other "modern" development environments don't have these limitations (I could be wrong?). You are right, we would need the answer directly from the one who made the decision. But that is interesting to hear, your bit on avoiding concerns about case sensitivity, I guess that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's not difficult to accept, it's just convention. 
You want to keep things separated, so just lowercase characters and underscores for you, if you work with UI components. Now, java/kotlin classes should be the CamelCase, with first letter on caps, and that's convention again.
It is not that difficult to follow, and it gives you so much more if you adopt it.

Comment: Absolutely, convention is convention. Nothing wrong with it at all as I've already grown accustomed to it these past years. I just find it odd, that other similar app dev environments like Xcode, or even the web, don't have these limitations. I just thought there was some interesting underlying reason it was done this way, that's all.